# Include bootstrap in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

When I type 
`npm install bootstrap`

I got this error:

```
 ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors                                                                           21:39:34
These dependencies were not found:

* !!vue-style-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"minimize":false,"importLoaders":1,"alias":{"/assets":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\assets","/static":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\static"}}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-82a4fe82","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":true}!sass-loader?{"indentedSyntax":true}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Index.1.vue in ./pages/Index.1.vue
* !!vue-style-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"minimize":false,"importLoaders":1,"alias":{"/assets":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\assets","/static":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\static"}}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-db198508","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":true}!sass-loader?{"indentedSyntax":true}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Index.vue in ./pages/Index.vue

To install them, you can run: npm install --save !!vue-style-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"minimize":false,"importLoaders":1,"alias":{"/assets":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\assets","/static":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\static"}}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-82a4fe82","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":true}!sass-loader?{"indentedSyntax":true}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Index.1.vue !!vue-style-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!css-loader?{"sourceMap":true,"minimize":false,"importLoaders":1,"alias":{"/assets":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\assets","/static":"E:\\Vueproject\\nuxtproject\\static"}}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler/index?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-db198508","scoped":true,"hasInlineConfig":true}!sass-loader?{"indentedSyntax":true}!../node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector?type=styles&index=0!./Index.vue

These relative modules were not found:

* ../.nuxt/components/Footer in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"babelrc":false,"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["E://Vueproject//nuxtproject//node_modules//babel-preset-vue-app//dist//index.common.js",{"targets":{"ie":9,"uglify":true}}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./pages/Index.vue* ../.nuxt/components/Footer.vue in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"babelrc":false,"cacheDirectory":true,"presets":[["E://Vueproject//nuxtproject//node_modules//babel-preset-vue-app//dist//index.common.js",{"targets":{"ie":9,"uglify":true}}]]}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./pages/Index.1.vue
```

What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The first part means you are missing some loaders that WebPack needs to bundle your styles.

Try running `npm install --save vue-style-loader css-loader` for that. It will install those two loaders.

`These relative modules were not found:` signals something else in your `Index` page, where you are trying to use the `Footer` component, but failed to import it or register it correctly. Have a look at the [Vue Docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Module-Systems) about registering your components.